# Can a std::ifstream/FILE* change size?

Tags: c++, c

Say I have the following code (which just opens a file, gets its size, and reads it all in one go):

```
std::ifstream file(path, std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
std::istream::streampos file_size = file.tellg();
file.seekg(0);
char* buffer = new char[file_size];
file.read(buffer, file_size);
```

Is it possible for the file to change size in between the `file.tellg()` and the `file.read()` calls (i.e. another program modifies the file)? That is, if `file.read()` succeeds, is it guaranteed that `file.gcount() == file_size`?

And extending this to C* (i.e. doing `fopen("rb")`, `fseek()`, `ftell()`, `rewind()`, `fread()`), if `fread()` succeeds, will it always return the file size (as previously reported by `ftell()`)?

I'm leaning towards this being implementation defined, but I'm curious if the C++ standard (or C standard, as the C++ standard refers to it for the `FILE`-related functions) makes any guarantees here or not.

<sub>*I'm working in C++, and there are two ways for me to work with files: `std::fstream` and `FILE*`. The C++ standard defers to the C standard regarding the `FILE*` functions, which is why I bring up C explicitly here.</sub>

Comment: since this is C++ code, suggest removing the 'c' tag

Comment: @user3629249: see the footnote. The C++ standard defers to the C standard regarding `FILE*` operations. Since I have two ways to work with files in C++ (`std::fstream` and `FILE*`), and I want to understand their guarantees, I have to ask about both C++ and C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I rather think this is dependant on the type of file you have open and the abilities of the operating system.

For the read to not behave as you expect, the file would have had to have shrunk between the `ftell` and the `fread`. You could have another process do that with `ftruncate`. And I can't find anything that says what happens to any other processes that have the file open. But I'd not expect them to necessarily be able to read the data that used to be there.

Answer (score 0):

The following experiment shows that a `std::ifstream`/`FILE*` can indeed change size while reading it:

**Writer1.cpp**:

```
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        std::ofstream file("file.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::trunc);
        file.flush();
        file << "Hello world!\n";
    }
}
```

**Reader1.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        std::ifstream file("file.txt", std::ios_base::binary | std::ios_base::ate);
        std::streamsize file_size = file.tellg();

        if (!file || file_size == -1) continue;

        file.seekg(0);
        char* buffer = new char[file_size];
        file.read(buffer, file_size);
        delete [] buffer;

        if (file.gcount() != file_size) {
            std::cout << file.gcount() << " != " << file_size << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Compiling `Writer1.cpp` and `Reader1.cpp` and running them at the same time eventually yields `0 != 13`, showing that `std::ifstream` can indeed change size between a `tellg()` and a `read()`.

**Writer2.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "wb");
        fflush(file);
        fwrite("Hello world!\n", 1, 13, file);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

**Reader2.cpp**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdio>

int main() {
    for (;;) {
        FILE* file = fopen("file.txt", "rb");
        if (!file) continue;

        fseek(file, 0, SEEK_END);
        long file_size = ftell(file);

        if (file_size == -1) {
            fclose(file);
            continue;
        }

        rewind(file);

        char* buffer = new char[file_size];
        size_t nread = fread(buffer, 1, file_size, file);
        fclose(file);
        delete [] buffer;

        if (nread != file_size) {
            std::cout << nread << " != " << file_size << std::endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Likewise, compiling `Writer2.cpp` and `Reader2.cpp` and running them at the same time eventually yields `0 != 13`, showing that a `FILE*` can indeed change size between a `ftell()` and a `fread()`.

Interestingly, `std::ifstream` fails faster for me than `FILE*` does. These tests were done on OS X 10.9.5 with clang 3.5.